# beginner Gradle error "dependency's AAR metadata"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

this my Gradle

```kotlin
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

```kotlin
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tablayout"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner defaultTestInstrumentationRunner
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies { 

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

this output:

> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata
> (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties) is greater
> than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-26). Dependency:
> androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2.

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear - your `compileSdkVersion` is too low. Did you try changing it to 31 like the error message says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` You have to get it to level `31`

Version 28 (intended for Android Pie and below) is the last version of the legacy support library, so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward.

Old:

`implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'`

New:

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'`

You can update the file like this:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.tablayout"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner defaultTestInstrumentationRunner
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies { 
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```